# Что должен знать Android junior

Tags: android

Хотел бы узнать у людей, которые работают сфере мобильного рынка. 
Каковы требования к человеку на должность android junior. Хотелось бы как можно по подробнее. А так же главный вопрос нужно ли иметь высшее образование?

Comment: Высшее образование необязательно, но это критерий по которому можно определить, что челове может довести дело доконца.

Comment: ну а какие знания нужны?

Comment: А спросить у работодателя? Или посмотреть по [вакансиям](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=вакансия%20junior%20java%20android)?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, нет устоявшихся требований к младшему программисту, ни в какой области. Кто-то может позволить себе нанять человека вообще без опыта, [пример](https://career.ru/vacancy/17974943):

> **Требования**:
>
> - Приличное образование, представление об общей культуре разработки,
> - Знание java core (в самом простом смысле) все-таки нужно,
> - Понимание как работают REST-сервисы будет определенным преимуществом,
> - Понимание, что такое JSON будет определенным преимуществом, хотя там и понимать нечего.
>
> Самый интенсивный курс доступен только на английском, поэтому хороший
>   английский будет тоже определенным преимуществом, хотя и не очень
>   существенным.
>
> **Условия**:
>
> - На время обучения (это займет от двух недель до двух месяцев) обязательно посещать офис в учебные часы и в часы персональных занятий
>     с ведущими программистами.
> - По завершению обучения мы выдадим вам тестовый личный проект, а потом подключим к одному из общих проектов.

А кто-то не может себе позволить такую роскошь, и требует выполнения какой-то работы сразу. Пусть не самой сложной, но ожидается именно работа, а не "я этого не умею, научите".

Поэтому уточнять нужно в каждом конкретном случае. Но одно можно сказать определённо: для джуниора не так важны знания какой-то узкой специфики, как общие знания (основ работы с БД, базовых алгоритмов, структур данных, понимания как работает компьютер, как устроены ОС, умение пользоваться инструментами разработки от VCS до отладки и профилирования...). И трезвая оценка своей подготовки (то есть если вы задаёте [подобные](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589589/) вопросы - смело вычёркивайте из резюме пункт про знание БД и срочно займитесь ликвидацией пробелов в этой области; если буковки `O(n)` вам ни о чём не говорят - зарыться в алгоритмы и т.д).