# Как в sqlite хранить такую структуру?

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

В рамках учебного проекта пишу бота  на python, который будет чекать фильмы с kinopoisk' и по указанию клиента заносить понравившиеся в очередь просмотра  ( пока просто база данных ). Для этого использую стандартный модуль sqlite3.C базой данных фильмов у клиента проблем нет.
На сервере должна храниться база данных с фильмами и id-шниками клиентов, у которых они стоят в очереди.

Вот тут вопрос, как сделать что-то типа динамического множества id и сопоставить его каждому фильму в sqlite и можно ли?
Имею в виду что-то в таком роде : Шрек -> [id1, id2, id3, ... и.т.д.]

Answer (score 2):

То что ты описываешь называется связь "Многие ко многим". В SQL это реализуется через промежуточную (между указанными тобой двумя) таблицу, в которой есть собственный ключ (не обязательно), и поле-ссылка на первую таблицу, и поле-ссылка на вторую таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE film(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    name INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE client(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    client_name TEXT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE film_client(
    film_id INTEGER,
    client_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(film_id) REFERENCES film(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY(client_id) REFERENCES client(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Вот так потом вставляются фильмы; клиенты; связи между ними

```
INSERT INTO film (name) VALUES ("Shrek");
INSERT INTO client (client_name) VALUES ("Ivan");
INSERT INTO film_client VALUES ((SELECT id FROM film WHERE name LIKE "Shrek"), (SELECT id FROM client WHERE client_name LIKE "Ivan"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно. Создайте в БД таблицу связей между фильмами и id клиентов (many-to-many).

В запросе указав id фильма, получите список id клиентов.